ampscript lookup does not work when field length of the lookup field is not set
This is my amp script code :
%%[
  Var @email
  Set @email = Lookup("forgot_password", "email","locale","en-US")
]%%
 %%=v(@email)=%%

The locale field length in the data extension is not set (unlimited).
I am getting an error:  The key field has a MAX or unlimited length. Fields with MAX or unlimited length cannot be used as keys
Is there an alternative way to do this without setting the field length? As I need to run the code for different data extension and the field length might not be set in all data extension

It is a really strange architectural choice to set a field to max length, if it is to store a locale, which is predefined to be 5 chars long. You will not be able to mitigate that in your ampscript.

My guess is that the email.forgot_password is holding all the HTML for an email.

@EduardoArias you are probably correct. But this would not explain why locale field has been set to varchar(MAX) as it would only hold a locale parameter, which would always be 5 char long

Agree with Lukas this is a very weird situation to deal with.
The real problem is elsewhere - I am not considering the below a "best practice": You are doomed to very "dumb" and limited workarounds.
But maybe this is worth something.
The limit really is in AMPScript that does not allow usage of unlimited field for lookup filters.
If dont use the field in a lookup filter, you should be fine.
So: If you creatively circumvent this, this would give you the option to work with the data as-is in your script.
What you can do is use LookupOrderedRows to retrieve "a lot of rows" by something else (limits apply, depending on how big your table is, be careful). Either you find something suitable, or you could set up a column that has the same value for EVERY record.
Then in a for loop over all retrieved rows, check locale, and if it matches, get the email. Obviously, this could return more than one email; Cant really say much on your data;
%%[
  /* 0 is set to Return all values - caution with large tables! */
  SET @myRowset = LookupOrderedRows("forgot_password",
    0,
    ,"email DESC"
    "isDeleted", "false"
  )
  SET @rowCount = RowCount(@myRowset)
  IF @rowCount > 0 THEN
    FOR @counter = 1 to @rowCount DO
      SET @row = Row(@myRowset, @counter)
      SET @locale = Field(@row, "locale")
      IF @locale == "en_US" THEN
        SET @email = Field(@row, "email")
        ]%%%%=v(@email)=%%%%[
      ENDIF
    NEXT @counter
  ENDIF
]%%

